# Converting Python2 hex variable to Python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, hex

I'm trying to convert a small file from Python2 to Python3.
This hex variable assignment is blocking me.

```
a = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFFFC2FL
```

The error I'm receiving is:

```
a = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFFFC2FL
                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Lose the `L`, it's redundant in Python 3 - all integers are long if they need to be.

Comment: Wow, thanks.. I was hoping it was easy :)

Answer (score 1):

Is there a problem if you remove the L? Is that not the value you expect?

```
>>> 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFFFC2F
115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663
```

Wolfram alpha thinks that's the correct value!